# How to calculate the transaction Id of a given signed transaction?

Tags: transaction, blake2b

How do you calculate the Id of a given transaction?

I have hex encoded signed transaction like this:

```
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
```

When I broadcasted the data, I got the following id:

`6eee20dfb476e0d113d22a18246bec044bbb857d97e892f0789e05d486b27fde`

So I was wondering if there's a way for me to calculate the id with given transaction data. I found this article:

https://emurgo.io/en/blog/understanding-unspent-transaction-outputs-in-cardano

and tried Blake2b256 hash, but it produced different value.

`76b1d252029ef367eb95c782968a41eb7bb1d6f4968f6f38be0ae03ec283bce4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for *blake2b-256* digest of the cbor-encoded transaction [body](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-ledger-specs/blob/master/eras/alonzo/test-suite/cddl-files/alonzo.cddl#L50-L65).

Thanks to [KtorZ](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/users/705/ktorz) to help with this.

Comment: I see, thank you!